# Why is SQL context_info lost on second database call?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper, transactionscope

Even though I'm using the same SQL connection, if I assign the context_info in one call, I lose it in the next call.

Why is this and how can I ensure context_info is retained for the other call?

See below for my minimal repro:

```
using var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);

await using var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.ConnectionString);

var parameters = new
{
    ContextInfo = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
};

// This assigns correctly
var first = await connection.QuerySingleAsync($@"
    SET CONTEXT_INFO @{nameof(parameters.ContextInfo)};

    SELECT CONTEXT_INFO();",
    parameters);

// This is null
var second = await connection.QuerySingleAsync("SELECT CONTEXT_INFO();");

scope.Complete();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not opening the connection yourself. That means Dapper will take care of opening and closing the connection on *each call*. Which means the second call is on a different (logical) connection.

Try adding `connection.Open();` (or, of course, `OpenAsync` if you prefer) before any Dapper calls